# How to handle BadPaddingException During AES256 encryption in C# and decryption in Java

Tags: java, c#, security, encryption, aes

I don't know why an error is coming up.

**Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded. Such issues can arise if a bad key is used during decryption.**

I understand that this error occurs when the incorrect key is used during the decryption. However, if you look at the test results result below, you can see that both C# and Java are the same (Key, IV, Salt is Base64 encoded).

1. C# Test Result

[image: C# Test Result]

2. Java Test Result

[image: Java Test Result]

**It's the same!(Key, IV, Salt)**

But the current BadpaddingException error is generated. What could be the problem?
I am attaching my source file.

1. C# (Encryption)

```
    class AES {
            private readonly static string keyStr = "This is Key";
            private readonly static string vector = "This is Vector";

            public static Rfc2898DeriveBytes MakeKey(string password){

                byte[] keyBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
                byte[] saltBytes = SHA512.Create().ComputeHash(keyBytes);
                Rfc2898DeriveBytes result = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(keyBytes, saltBytes, 65536);

                return result;
            }

            public static Rfc2898DeriveBytes MakeVector(string vector){

                byte[] vectorBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(vector);
                byte[] saltBytes = SHA512.Create().ComputeHash(vectorBytes);
                Rfc2898DeriveBytes result = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(vectorBytes, saltBytes, 65536);

                return result;
            }

            public static void Encrypt(String inputFile, String outputFile) {
                using (RijndaelManaged aes = new RijndaelManaged()){
                    //Create Key and Vector
                    Rfc2898DeriveBytes key = AES.MakeKey(AES.keyStr);
                    Rfc2898DeriveBytes vector = AES.MakeVector(AES.vector);

                    //AES256
                    aes.BlockSize = 128;
                    aes.KeySize = 256;

                    // It is equal in java 
                    // Cipher _Cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING");    
                    aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC; 
                    aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7; 
                    aes.Key = key.GetBytes(32); //256bit key
                    aes.IV  = vector.GetBytes(16); //128bit block size


                    //processing Encrypt
                    ICryptoTransform encryptor = aes.CreateEncryptor(aes.Key, aes.IV);
                    byte[] encrypted;

                    using (MemoryStream msEncrypt = new MemoryStream()) { 
                            using (CryptoStream csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write)) {
                                byte[] inputBytes = File.ReadAllBytes(inputFile);
                                csEncrypt.Write(inputBytes, 0, inputBytes.Length);
                            }
                            encrypted = msEncrypt.ToArray();     
                        }
                        string encodedString = Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);
                        File.WriteAllText(outputFile, encodedString);
                    }
                }
            }
```

2. Java (Decryption)

```
    public class AES256File {
        private static final String algorithm = "AES";
        private static final String blockNPadding = algorithm+"/CBC/PKCS5Padding";
        private static final String password = "This is Key";
        private static final String IV = "This is Vector";

        private static IvParameterSpec ivSpec;
        private static Key keySpec;

        public static void MakeKey(String password) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException, InvalidKeySpecException{
            SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
            MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
            byte[] keyBytes = password.getBytes("UTF-8");

            // C# : byte[] saltBytes = SHA512.Create().ComputeHash(keyBytes);
            byte[] saltBytes = digest.digest(keyBytes);

            //256bit
            PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(password.toCharArray(), saltBytes, 65536, 256);
            Key secretKey = factory.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);

            byte[] key = new byte[32];
            System.arraycopy(secretKey.getEncoded(), 0, key, 0, 32);

            SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");
            setKeySpec(secret);
        }

        public static void MakeVector(String IV) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, UnsupportedEncodingException, InvalidKeySpecException{
            SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
            MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-512");
            byte[] vectorBytes = IV.getBytes("UTF-8");
            byte[] saltBytes = digest.digest(vectorBytes);

            // 128bit
            PBEKeySpec pbeKeySpec = new PBEKeySpec(IV.toCharArray(), saltBytes, 65536, 128);
            Key secretIV = factory.generateSecret(pbeKeySpec);

            byte[] iv = new byte[16];
            System.arraycopy(secretIV.getEncoded(), 0, iv, 0, 16);

            IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
            setIvSpec(ivSpec);
        }

        public void decrypt(File source, File dest) throws Exception {
            Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(blockNPadding);
            c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);
            fileProcessing(source, dest, c);
        }

        public  void fileProcessing(File source, File dest, Cipher c) throws Exception{
            InputStream input = null;
            OutputStream output = null;

            try{
                input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(source));
                output = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(dest));
                byte[] buffer = new byte[input.available()];
                int read = -1;
                while((read = input.read(buffer)) != -1){
                    output.write(c.update(buffer, 0, read));
                }
                byte[] deryptedBytes = c.doFinal(buffer); // -----------------------> Error!! Showing! 
                byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(deryptedBytes);
                String decodeString = new String(decodedBytes, "UTF-8");
                decodedBytes = decodeString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                output.write(decodedBytes);

            }finally{
                if(output != null){
                    try{output.close();}catch(IOException e){}
                }
                if(input != null){
                    try{input.close();}catch(IOException e){}
                }
            }
        }
```

**I have verified as below.**

1. Verification Key and IV in **C#**

```
    //Key Verification
        var salt = Convert.ToBase64String(saltBytes);
                Console.Write("Salt Result : ");
                Console.WriteLine(salt);

        var result_test = Convert.ToBase64String(result.GetBytes(32));
                Console.Write("Key Test Result: ");
                Console.WriteLine(result_test);
    //IV Verification (Salt is Using same code)
        var result_test = Convert.ToBase64String(result.GetBytes(16));
                Console.Write("IV Test Result: ");
                Console.WriteLine(result_test);
```

2. Verification Key and IV in **Java**

```
    //Key Verification
        /* print Salt */
        String base64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(saltBytes);
        System.out.println("Salt Result : " + base64);

        /* print Key */
        String result_test = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(key);
        System.out.println("Key Test Result : " + result_test);

        /* print generated Key */
        System.out.println("Secret Key Result : " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(secret.getEncoded()));

    //IV Verification (Salt is Using same code)
        /* print IV */
        String result_test = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(iv);
        System.out.println("IV Test Result : " + result_test);

        /* print generated IV */
        System.out.println("IV Result : " + Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(ivSpec.getIV()));
```

**Updated**

**c# .netframework 4.5 / Java8** modified what @Topaco said and confirmed that it worked well.

I want to say thank you very much to @Topaco and @Gusto2, and I'm going to make changes to the parts that have been modified in security, just as @Gusto2 said!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) In the C# `Encrypt`-method the plain text is encrypted first and then Base64-encoded. Thus, in the decryption process the data must be Base64-decoded first and then decrypted. Currently this is handled in the wrong order i.e. the data are decrypted first and then decoded. Therefore, in the Java `fileProcessing`-method replace

```
while((read = input.read(buffer)) != -1){
    output.write(c.update(buffer, 0, read));
}
```

with

```
while((read = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    byte[] bufferEncoded = buffer;
    if (read != buffer.length) { 
        bufferEncoded = Arrays.copyOf(buffer, read);
    }
    byte[] bufferDecoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(bufferEncoded);
    output.write(c.update(bufferDecoded));
}
```

2) It's not necessary to pass `buffer` (or `bufferDecoded`) to the `doFinal`-method, since that was already done in the `update`-method. Thus,

```
byte[] deryptedBytes = c.doFinal(buffer);
```

must be replaced with

```
output.write(c.doFinal());
```

3) Since the Base64-decoding is already done in 1) in the `try`-block all lines following the `doFinal`-statement have to be removed. Overall, this results in

```
try {
    input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(source));
    output = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(dest));
    byte[] buffer = new byte[input.available()];
    int read = -1;
    while((read = input.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        byte[] bufferEncoded = buffer;
        if (read != buffer.length) { 
            bufferEncoded = Arrays.copyOf(buffer, read);
        }
        byte[] bufferDecoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(bufferEncoded);
        output.write(c.update(bufferDecoded));
    }
    output.write(c.doFinal()); 
}
```

4) The size of the buffer has to be a multiple of 4 in order to ensure a proper Base64-decoding. Thus, it's more reliable to replace

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[input.available()];
```

with

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[4 * (input.available() / 4)];
```

As long as the data are read in one chunk (which is not guaranteed, see e.g. https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html#available()) there is no problem. However, if the data are read in several chunks it's important to read a multiple of 4 bytes, otherwise the Base64-decoding will fail. That can be easily proved by using a buffer size which isn't a multiple of 4. This point must also be considered if the buffer size is *explicitly* defined with regard to larger files.

Comment: I got a lot of help with your answers, and I found out that my decoding order was wrong, but what is the reason for the error to still be output as a result?

Comment: I didn't change the c# code, and I changed it by referring to your test source, but BadPaddingException continues to be the result. Can I check your test source by any chance?

Comment: Well, it works well when it's running on another computer (Java 10) but strangely, it doesn't work on my computer (Java 8). Thank you very much! I'll continue to look at the causes (BadPaddingException).

Answer (score 1):

```
while((read = input.read(buffer)) != -1){
       output.write(c.update(buffer, 0, read));
}
byte[] deryptedBytes = c.doFinal(buffer)
```

you are decrypting the input to a file, then you are using the same cipher instance to decrypt the the last read chunk (again) into a separate array not to the file

quick fix:

```
while((read = input.read(buffer)) != -1){
       output.write(c.update(buffer, 0, read));
}
output.write(c.doFinal()); // write the padded block
```

if you want to create and print a decrypted String, you need to create a new Cipher instance  (or maybe it will be enough to reinitialize the instance, I am not sure) assuming the buffer contains the whole input

```
c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);
// assuming the buffer contains the whole input again
byte[] deryptedBytes = c.doFinal(buffer); // decrypting the whole file again
```

correct approach:

- IV is used to securely reuse the same encryption key for multiple encryptions. So if your key is not random, you should generate new random IV for each encryption (and pass the IV along the ciphertext, most often prepended). Otherwise the encryption is not semantically secure and you may create opening for the two pad attack. So deriving IV from the key may not be very secure.
- I advice to use any MAC (authentication code) passed along the ciphertext to ensure integrity (e.g. HMAC)
- you are still reading all the file input fully into memory, what would not work for REALLY LARGE files. You may initialize the buffer to an arbitrary length (a few MB?) and process the input file as chunked